# my login page in codeigniter not working with postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, authentication

i have login page in codeigniter but it does not working with postresql ?

this my database config:

```
$active_group = 'default';
    $query_builder = TRUE;

    $db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '5433',
    'username' => 'postgres',
    'password' => '12345',
    'database' => 'arahenvi',
    'dbdriver' => 'postgre',    
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
    );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the community guidelines on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A good question should include the steps you've tried and errors you're seeing for example.

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a `dsn` string

```
$db['default'] = array(
  'dsn'   => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5433;dbname=arahenvi',
  ...
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: invalid connection option "pgsql:hostname"

Filename: postgre/postgre_driver.php

Line Number: 154

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\arah\application\controllers\Home.php
Line: 5
Function: __construct

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\arah\index.php
Line: 316
Function: require_once

Comment: my login page is show, but this error show. A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

Filename: drivers/Session_database_driver.php

Line Number: 183

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\arah\application\controllers\Authentication.php
Line: 7
Function: __construct

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\arah\index.php
Line: 316
Function: require_once